# Laravel 8: where are the default routes?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Where are the default routes for auth and teams in laravel 8 using the inertia stack?

in laravel 7 you would see something like `Auth::routes()` in `web.php`

now all that is in there is:-

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {
    return Inertia\Inertia::render('Dashboard');
})->name('dashboard');
```

no sign of the auth or new teams scaffolding routes, anybody know how/where these are defined?

Comment: yea they are in the jetstream package, they are loaded with their service provider so they are not in any of your route files

Comment: You can use php artisan route:list and there you get info about your routes and controller location. This can be helpful because the routes usually come from the same package (controllers might be published of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Laravel 8, the [Jetstream](https://jetstream.laravel.com/1.x/introduction.html) package is used for scaffolding instead of `Laravel UI`.

> Laravel's `laravel/jetstream` package provides a quick way to scaffold all of the routes, views, and other backend logic needed for authentication using a few simple commands.

Installing the package will install a layout view, registration and login views, as well as routes for all authentication end-points. A /dashboard route will also be generated to handle post-login requests to your application's dashboard..

Laravel Jetstream  registrates the routes from the `JetstreamServiceProvider` by default and can be turned off through `Jetstream::ignoreRoutes();`.

Jetstream instructions: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#authentication-quickstart

---

In Laravel 6/7, you instead had `Laravel UI` for scaffolding these stuff.

> Laravel UI will install a layout view, registration and login views, as well as routes for all authentication end-points. A HomeController will also be generated to handle post-login requests to your application's dashboard.

> The laravel/ui package also generates several pre-built authentication controllers, which are located in the App\Http\Controllers\Auth namespace. The RegisterController handles new user registration, the LoginController handles authentication, the ForgotPasswordController handles e-mailing links for resetting passwords, and the ResetPasswordController contains the logic to reset passwords. Each of these controllers uses a trait to include their necessary methods. For many applications, you will not need to modify these controllers at all.

Laravel UI uses `Auth::routes()`.

Laravel Ui instructions: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#authentication-quickstart